# How do I get emacs to reconise my python 3 virtual environment

Tags: python, django, emacs

My system is a Mac and I have both python 2 and 3 installed. I am currently working on a side project for which I want to use django 1.8 and python 3.4.

I have created a virtual environment with the python 3 command `pyvenv venv` in the parent folder of my project (I prefer to have my python project folders to be self contained).

At the moment, I cannot get emacs to recognise and therefore limit all code related assist to the virtual environment.

In addition, is it possible to setup a per project settings such that I can have different projects use different python versions and environment? The ideal scenario will be, when I change into a project directory and start emacs, it will pick all it's environment settings from that project directory according to some local settings file.

I've been seeking help on google and irc for a while now without success.

Comment: You might get a faster answer on [Emacs stack exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Gee thanks! I didn't know there was a dedicated emacs stack exchange. I'm going to post over there then. What is the best practice; should I leave this post here or delete it since I'm pasting it on another stack exchange site?

Comment: I think there's a feature that lets you link to the emacs question from this one but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP moved it to emacs.stackexchange, [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13489/105).